# How to sum the selected values from the radio button and pass to submit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I need the sum the values from the selected radio button and add to the submit button.

Find the code below :

```
 <?php foreach($configure['options']['option'] as $options)
  {
  ?>

<label class="containerRadio">{{$options['name']}}
<input type="radio" class="calc" name="{{$name}}" value=" 
 {{$configure['id']}}_{{$options['id']}}-{{$options['name']}}- 
 {{$options['pricing']['INR']['monthly']}}" checked="checked">
 <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>

 <?php } ?> </div><br><br> <?php } ?><input type="text" name="sum"></button>
 <button type="submit" name="sum"><i class="fa fa-rupee" aria-hidden="true"> 
 </i> {{$key['monthly']}}
 </button>
```

Fimd below the javascript :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
function calcscore(){
var score = 0;
$(".calc:checked").each(function(){
    score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
});
$("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}
$().ready(function(){
$(".calc").change(function(){
    calcscore()
});
});
</script>
```

Suggest a solution to add the value selected from the radio button to the default value given as "{{$key['monthly']}}".

Comment: You're mixing blade templates and php code in your template. Make sure you understand the difference.

Comment: You could add `data-initial="{{$key['monthly']}}"` to your submit button. Retrieve it with `element.getAttribute("data-initial")` and add to the radiobutton value.